# Transition Kernel as Operator on an Integrable function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm reading "Monte Carlo Statistical Methods" by Robert and Casella. On Pg 211, in the chapter "Markov Chains," we have the following statement:

$$Kh(x) = \int h(y) K(x, dy)$$

where $K$ is a transition kernel and $h$ is an integrable function.

I don't understand how to interpret $dy$ in this since it is an argument to the transition kernel. What is the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if $K$ is a Markov kernel, then $K(x,\cdot)$ is measure, while $K(\cdot, A)$ is a measurable function. Hence, $\int h(y) K(x,\textrm{d}y)$ means integrate $h$ with respect to the measure $K(x,\cdot)$. Measurability of $K$ in $x$ then guarantees measurability of the resulting function.